# Selenium Web Driver getPageSource() Misplacing Attributes And Values Containing Escaped Values

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

While using selenium, just now i got an error while parsing the output from selenium `getPageSource()` method.
The actual meta tag on page source of firefox =

```
  <meta name="news_keywords" content="devo max,independence vote,no campaign,referendum,scotland \"no\" vote,scotland independence,scotland powers,scotland referendum,scotland vote,scottish referendum" />
```

getPageSource() method result using firefox driver with selenium =

```
<meta referendum"="" vote,scottish="" referendum,scotland="" powers,scotland="" independence,scotland="" vote,scotland="" no\"="" content="devo max,independence vote,no campaign,referendum,scotland \" name="news_keywords" />
```

Its very absurd and creating problems in further processing of the html output.
Any suggestions or help or workaround?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> getPageSource
>
> java.lang.String getPageSource()
>
> Get the source of the last loaded page. If the page has been modified
>   after loading (for example, by Javascript) there is no guarantee that
>   the returned text is that of the modified page. Please consult the
>   documentation of the particular driver being used to determine whether
>   the returned text reflects the current state of the page or the text
>   last sent by the web server. The page source returned is a
>   representation of the underlying DOM: do not expect it to be formatted
>   or escaped in the same way as the response sent from the web server.
>   Think of it as an artist's impression.
>
> Returns:
>       The source of the current page

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getPageSource%28%29

Comment: any way to get it the way it should be ? i mean the proper way ?